# Allow single ,double quote and full stop with Regex

Tags: php, regex, cakephp

I have implement validation with cake php model only letters allowed. below is code

```
'referer' => array(
    'notempty3' => array(
        'rule'      => '/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/',
        'message' => 'Only letters allowed.',
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'required' => true,
        //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
        //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
    )
)
```

but i want add allow single ,double quote and full stop with letters.

Comment: could you show us some samples of valid and invalid inputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then change the regex to:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s'".]+$/
```

You just need to add them in the character class.

Comment: You'll obviously need to escape that `\` and `'`

Comment: @pguardiario yes like that -> 'rule'      => '/^[a-zA-Z\s\'\".]+$/',

Comment: @vikam, no more like '/^[a-zA-Z\\s\'".]+$/'